# Make an image appear when page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, image, button, reload

I am new to Java so please don't hate!
I want to make an image appear in a game every time a button is pressed to clear the previous score how do I make this image appear only when the page is first loaded and when the button to start again is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is javaSCRIPT ;) You should [google](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_events_examples.asp) it, furthermore it has been answered before. However, I think the most simple way to handle events in javascript, and to handle them only once all the page is loaded is :

```
window.onload = function(){
    initialization();
}

function initialization(){
    //on page loading
    document.getElementById("yourimage").style.display = "inline-block";
    document.getElementById("yourimage").style.visibility = "visible";
    //on click event
    document.getElementById("buttonToStartAgain").onclick = function(){
        document.getElementById("yourimage").style.display = "inline-block";
        document.getElementById("yourimage").style.visibility = "visible";
    }
}
```